# use a console to add references, similar to nuget

Tags: visual-studio

I like the nuget package manager console because when I know exactly what I want it is quicker to type than go through a GUI, eg.

```
install-package NUnit -project MyProject.UnitTests
```

After using this I find the standard VS Add Reference dialog very cumbersome. I'd like to be able to add a reference like this...

```
add-reference System.Data.Linq -project MyProject.UnitTests
```

Is there any such tool?

Comment: How often do you find yourself adding references? It's something I do sufficiently rarely that taking a few seconds over it really doesn't contribute a significant impact to the time taken for a project. How long do you think you spend adding references over the course of, say, a year?

Comment: Is something preventing you from writing such a console?

Comment: @JonSkeet. More frequently than I install external packages with nuget. If there's a case for it in nuget, then there's a case for it in general. As an approximation, I'd say 10 times/week. I'm also using F#, which comes with much fewer project templates.

Comment: @Javaman59: NuGet started life with mostly the console. Have you considered modifying the F# templates instead?

Comment: The question is "Is there such a tool?". The most efficient solution for me, rather than writing a tool myself, or modifying the F# templates, is to use one which already exists. Yes, I googled it, and found nothing. Maybe I should have mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: I have searched for "add.reference console", "Visual Studio add reference command line" and similar, and found nothing. However, there may be other ways to describe such a tool. It may be a small part of another tool set. It may be in development somewhere. It may be possible with some minor customisation of Visual Studio.